# How to assign a cat() value to an object in r

Tags: r, object

I have a character vector that I would like to process some functions on it.

```
vars <- c("1234_AS_SA1_PCNS","2345_AS_SA2_UDA", "3823_AS_SA3_CL")


cat(dQuote(paste0("Equal = ", paste("(", vars, ", Slope[0])",
                                          collapse=",\n ", sep=""), ";"), FALSE))
```

The above procedure prints this:

```
"Equal = (1234_AS_SA1_PCNS, Slope[0]),
 (2345_AS_SA2_UDA, Slope[0]),
 (3823_AS_SA3_CL, Slope[0]);"
```

My question is that how can I save this character variable in an object?

When I assigned this procedure to an object,

```
aa <- cat(dQuote(paste0("Equal = ", paste("(", vars, ", Slope[0])",
                                          collapse=",\n ", sep=""), ";"), FALSE))
```

I get aa NUll:

```
> aa
NULL
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: By default when you type a variable in the console, it's routed through the `print()` function to make it look pretty. The `print()` function automatically escapes special characters so as not to confuse the console. The `cat()` function draws the string without the escaping and returns NULL so nothing additional gets printed. If you store the value inside the `cat()`, that's the string you want. But if you want to display it without escaping it, you will always need to `cat()` that string value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cat` doesn't have a `return` value.  It just `print`.  We could write the output to a file by specifying the `file` argument

```
cat(dQuote(paste0("Equal = ", paste("(", vars, ", Slope[0])",
                                      collapse=",\n ", sep=""), ";"), FALSE),
     file = 'file.txt')
```

---

The `dQuote` output can be assigned and not the `cat` wrapped on it

```
aa <- dQuote(paste0("Equal = ", paste("(", vars, ", Slope[0])",
                                      collapse=",\n ", sep=""), ";"), FALSE)
```

Comment: aa prints out this `"\"Equal = (1234_AS_SA1_PCNS, Slope[0]),\n (2345_AS_SA2_UDA, Slope[0]),\n (3823_AS_SA3_CL, Slope[0]);\""`. Is it possible to place an indent after each value? I thought `collapse=",\n"` adds that indentation.

Comment: @amisos55 Perhaps you want `collapse=",\n\t"`

Comment: it prints `[1] "\"Equal = (1234_AS_SA1_PCNS, Slope[0]),\n\t(2345_AS_SA2_UDA, Slope[0]),\n\t(3823_AS_SA3_CL, Slope[0]);\""`. not sure why it prints everything in the paranthesis.

Comment: @amisos55 What is the ultimate objective?  Is it to pass as strings or store as output in file.  If it is write it to file, then use `cat` with `file` option

Comment: I guess this should work. I was using some other format to export the values, this will be much better since the other way I was using did not let me the indentation and eventually, that file leads to many errors. Thanks!